# MySql not starting during startup even after adding symlink to rc5.d

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I recently added `mysql.server` to start during the start up by doing this:

```
cd /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/
ln -s  /etc/init.d/mysql.server S98mysql
```

I have perhaps not correctly understood the `<number>` part of `s<number>script` / `k<number>script` naming convention for the RC scripts.

Although, I know that it's for: representing the order in which the script will be executed during the run of runlevel control script.

Picked up `S98mysql` from: [How To Install MySQL **:** 6.0 Automatic MySQL Start-up during boot](http://www.icthus.net/CGI-City/tut_mysql_install.shtml)

But MySQL does not start during startup. Will show this message when trying to connect (as expected):

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Works fine if I do a manual start with: `/etc/init.d/mysql.server start` 
What am I doing wrong?

I am using `Fedora 15`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Fedora you might want to use [`chkconfig`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html).

To see what run levels a particular service is enabled for, you can do something like this

```
chkconfig --list <servicename>
```

Ex:

```
chkconfig --list mysqld
```

To change the behavior for certain run levels for a service you can do something like this:

```
chkconfig --levels 345 mysqld on
```

or since your init.d script has a different name

```
chkconfig --levels 345 mysql.server on
```

If a service isn't listed in `chkconfig` you can add it with the `--add` flag. Use the script name found in `/etc/init.d`.

Ex:

```
chkconfig --add mysql.server
```

Wikipedia has more information on [run levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel).

Most servers only go to run level 3 which would mean that run level 5 is not reached so the service would not be started in your example.

Most desktops go to run level 5 since that is when the graphical interface (X) starts.

Comment: `mysql.server` script says:
`# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5`
`# Default-Stop: 0 1 6`
where as the `chkconfig --list` does not list `mysql` at all though `S98mysql` is present in `cd /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/`.

Comment: The start levels in the script are what chkconfig uses for default values. Try adding the service with "chkconfig --add mysql.server"  Also you can set a list of all the services that are managed with chkconfig by running "chkconfig --list"

Comment: hmmm looking into it.

Comment: did this `chkconfig --add mysql.server` and a reboot to my system. MySQL is starting as expected. Thank you.